# What is a seed file?

Tags: upload, seed

I have been given a task to upload a file and store it in a different location. And I need to return a seed file which should be used to retrieve the file again.

I'm done with all sorts of things but I can't get **"what is a seed file and how can generate it and how can I retrieve the file later with that"**

can someone help me with this?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your context, but `seed` is usually a file (or a template) that contains some default values to begin with.

Comment: can I know what is the extension for it? and Where Can I Study about this

Comment: It really depends, can we get some more context? What are you working on, how are you uploading?

Answer (score 0):

Historical data being loaded into a table or tables (structures) hence seeding the file.  This is usually done to get the history caught up with the integration.  There is usually lag between a new structure/automation and the API going live.